# Combine array values into a single value to display in a single column of a grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, telerik

I have an MVC3 app using the telerik's grid control. I'm populating the grid fine but my model that i use has an array inside of it that needs to be displayed in a single column. Heres my model

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string parentName {get; set;}
    public string[] childrenNames { get; set; }
}
```

Now populate my class with data in the controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
            var loo = new MyModel[2];
            loo[0] = new MyModel();
            loo[0].parentName = "Troy";
            loo[0].childrenNames[0] = "chris";
            loo[0].childrenNames[1] = "tony";
            loo[1] = new MyModel();
            loo[1].parentName = "Mike";
            loo[1].childrenNames[0] = "lee";
            loo[1].childrenNames[1] = "mary";

            IEnumerable<MyModel> model = loo;
        return View(model);

 }
```

Now my childrenNames array can and will have more than one entry, but I need the childrenNames to be combined into one value seperated by commas and displayed in my grid:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyModel>
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(o => o.parentName).Width(100).Title("Parent");
    columns.Bound(o => o.childrenNamesCombined).Width(250).Title("Kids");
 }
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have an array as a single column

You should make it string in the Model, or have another property with the joined array:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string parentName {get; set;}
    public string[] childrenNames { get; set; }
    public string JoinedNames { get; set; }
}

loo[1] = new MyModel();
..
...
loo[1].JoinedNames  = string.Join("," loo[1].childrenNames);

@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(o => o.parentName).Width(100).Title("Parent");
    columns.Bound(o => o.JoinedNames).Width(250).Title("Kids");
 }
```